# Save location with geofire on an existing document

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I want an using firebase real time database to store events of some sort.
An event can have a changing status in its life cycle.

I want to be able to fetch all active events near a user current location.

Because it doesn't seems like geofire enables me to save the location on the event document, I would have to get all events near the location, and then filter by status and given event ids (is that event possible??).

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Geofire works by returning what's close to coordinates you give it. For an idea or starter template, check out [https://getaa.org](https://getaa.org/). (click the map icon top center and enter 'san francisco' or 'baton rouge' if you are in an area with no meetings.

The [code is all on github](https://github.com/rhroyston/getaa.org).

[image]

Here's a code snippet:

```
function loadQuery(lat,lng,today){
        //console.log('loadQuery function fired with ' + lat,lng,today);
        var geoKeys = [];
        var records=[];


        var geoQuery = geofire.query({
            center: [lat,lng],
            radius: radius
        });

        var onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
            geoKeys.push(key);
            //console.log('geoQuery event KEY ENTERED with key: ' + key);
        });

        // GeoKeys now in array
        var onReadyRegistration = geoQuery.on("ready", function() {

            //console.log('geoQuery event READY');

            if(geoKeys.length > 0){
                toastUp('Fetching Meetings...');
                // Get recordset for each key into sites array
                readFirebaseNodes(geoKeys).then(function(value) {
                    //filter for today
                    var todaysMeetings = dayFilter(today);
                    drop(todaysMeetings);
                }, function(err) {
                  //console.log(err); // Error!
                });
            } else {
                toastUp('No area meetings found.  You are encouraged to volunteer to add them.  Click <a href="/admin">Meetings Manager</a> to become a site administrator.');
                toastDown(2000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database can only query on a single property. The fact that GeoFire can filter on two axes (longitude and latitude) is already quite magical (thanks to the use of geohashes). Adding one more value to the mix is beyond what GeoFire is made for.

But it's actually quite simple to only show nearby *active* events: keep a location/reference in your database with just the locations of those *active* events. Then you can simply create a `GeoFire` object on that location, and it will only find nearby *active* events:

```
// Create a Firebase reference where GeoFire will store its information
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("activeEventLocations");

// Create a GeoFire index
var geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);
```